# Viewing a WordPress website in landscape

Tags: mobile, optimization, support

I have a client that wants to landscape support for his website.
I have never needed to optimize a website for landscape view nor did it ever cross my mind.
If possible how do I do it on WordPress?

Comment: Use css & [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation) `@media (orientation: landscape) {` or [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) in javaScript

Comment: Don't all responsive websites support landscapes out of the box?

Comment: Turns out the guy didn't have his auto-rotate on. I apologise for the pointless question.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the guy didn't have his auto-rotate on. I apologise for the pointless question.